# Extracting non-whitespace contents between pairs of keywords in a long string in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract content between two strings (for example, `Str. A.` and `Str. B.`) in R. The rule is, if there's only whitespace between the two strings (for example, `Str. A. Str. B.`), search for the next match of the right boundary (that is, `Str. B.`) and extract the content inbetween.

For instance, I have the following string:

`"Str. A. Str. B. Str. B. Some data. Str. A. More data. Str. B. Other data. Str. A. Str. B. Str. B. Some more data."`

I call the boundary strings keywords. **I used `Str. A.` and `Str. B.` for illustration purposes. In the actual data, there's no pattern in the keywords themselves or the order of the keywords (such as `Str. A.`, then `Str. B.`, then `Str. A`, then `Str. B.`)** even though I do have the entire list of the keywords. In the example, I would have a list of keywords such as

`"Str. A." "Str. B." "Str. A." "Str. B." "Str. A." "Str. B."`

With the above keywords and the non-whitespace extraction rule, my desired output is as follows.

```r
keywords content
Str. A.  Str. B.            
Str. B.  Some data.         
str. A.  More data.         
Str. B.  Other data.
Str. A.  Str. B.
Str. B.  Some more data.
```

In summary, I am trying to extract non-whitespace contents between pairs of keywords in a long string. I read two other posts related to extraction between two strings on stackoverflow but the answers didn't help. I also played with [Regex.com](https://regexr.com/) but couldn't figure it out.

I tried `strsplit()` but couldn't get past the whitespace between the keywords. A different approach I used was to use regex to extract the keyword and the non-whitespace content after it, then remove the extraction from the string and move on to the next keyword. Again, I couldn't get past the whitespace between two keywords.

**Edit**: If there was no white-space in the keywords, such as `Str.A.`, `Str.B.`, the string would have become

`Str.A. Str.B. Str.B. Some data. Str.A. More data. Str.B. Other data. Str.A. Str.B. Str.B. Some more data.`

Then I was able to use `^Str\\.A\\.\\s+(\\S+)\\s+Str\\.B\\.` to extract the non-whitespace content (the first `Str.B.`) between the keywords. I may remove the whitespace in the keywords as a last resort.

Comment: You may want to use a combination of regex and data wrangling let me ilustrate in the answers below

Answer (score 0):

```
 library(tidyverse)
    df<-data.frame(string=c("Str. A. Str. B. Str. B. Some data. Str. A. More data. Str. B. Other data. Str. A. Str. B. Str. B. Some more data."))
    
      df %>% 
      mutate(string=stringr::str_replace_all(string,"Str\\. A\\.\\s","SEPStr. A.SEP")) %>% 
      mutate(string=stringr::str_replace_all(string,"Str\\. B\\.\\s","SEPStr. B.SEP")) %>%
      separate_rows(string,sep="SEP") %>% 
      filter(str_length(string)>0) %>% 
      mutate(key=str_detect(string,"Str\\. \\w")) %>% 
      mutate(keywords=ifelse(key==TRUE,string,NA)) %>%
      mutate(content=lead(string)) %>% 
      filter(!(keywords==content)) %>% 
      select(keywords,content)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  keywords content          
  <chr>    <chr>            
1 Str. A.  "Str. B."        
2 Str. B.  "Some data. "    
3 Str. A.  "More data. "    
4 Str. B.  "Other data. "   
5 Str. A.  "Str. B."        
6 Str. B.  "Some more data."
```

**Let me guide you through the process:**

we first change the structure of tke keywords to add at the begining and end a delimiter in this case the word "SEP"

```
 df %>% 
      mutate(string=stringr::str_replace_all(string,"Str\\. A\\.\\s","SEPStr. A.SEP")) %>% 
      mutate(string=stringr::str_replace_all(string,"Str\\. B\\.\\s","SEPStr. B.SEP")) %>%
```

secondly we use thw function separate_rows to split by "SEP" (the aux delimiter we created) and you have to keep in mind that this will keep the order in which the string was splitted, after that we remove any rows with 0 strings or "" (they occured because of words boundaries)

```
separate_rows(string,sep="SEP") %>% 
  filter(str_length(string)>0) %>%
```

afterwards we identify the `keywords` and we do so by detecting the pattern we had, and keep in mind that if the string is not a keyword then it is `content`

```
mutate(key=str_detect(string,"Str\\. \\w")) %>% 
mutate(keywords=ifelse(key==TRUE,string,NA)) %>%
```

your desired output is pivoted fixed and condition on `keywords` followed by another keyword or `content` and so create a column named content that is the lead of each string, that means the content is the following word in the string column, we finally filter redundant combinations and select our two desired columns

```
mutate(content=lead(string)) %>% 
+   filter(!(keywords==content)) %>% 
+   select(keywords,content)
```

Please dont forget to select this answer if it best suited your question also vote up if this helps!have a great day! and you are always welcome !